# Problem using "connect()" within an iteration in qt4 with clicked() signals and using information from the iteration in the corresponding slot

Tags: qt4, iterator, signals-slots, click

For this, I'm programming in c++ using qt4 to design my interface.

In this program, I create a widget which spawns a (unknown) number QPushButtons depending on user input, thus I am creating them dynamically. At the moment of creation, I want to connect these buttons to a function that would need parameters that exist within the iteration of creating the buttons (for example, an int that would indicate a position in the a vector), yet I cannot do this due to the nature of signals/slots and the nature of the clicked() signal from the QPushButtons (it does not accept parameters).

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
vector<int> myVector

for(int i=0; i<user_input_number; i++){

    ...
    QPushButton *testingb4 = new QPushButton("Execute", this);
    connect( testingb4, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( customSlot() ) );
    ...

}
```

"customSlot" would need "i" to determine what element of my vector I should access. How do I get solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsignalmapper.html). This may help you identify the source of click signals.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for as it allows me to map "parameters" into the clicked() signals without violating the syntax required of them. Should've read the Qt4 documentation a tad more thoroughly, since I'm still a little new to Qt4.

Thank you very much @OrcunC